# Rails Passing Object to Form Partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, partials

`rails 5`, `ruby 2.5`

I'm trying something new for me. In my head it makes sense but it is not working.  I want to put a `<form>` tag on my `new` and `edit` views, then call a partial, which has the rest of the form. I'm passing in the "instance variable" (correct term?) `f` using `:locals`, but it is not recognized in the partial.

```
# new.html.erb

<% @page_title = "New Food Entry" %>

<%= form_for(@food) do |f| %>

  <%= render "form", :locals => { :f => f  } %> 

<% end %>
```

```
# _form.html.erb

<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" style="border: 1px solid #369;" summary="Edit or new Food Record">

  <tr>                                                                        
    <td><label>Food Name</label></td>                                                   
    <td><%= f.text_field :food_item, :size => 30 %></td>
  </tr>
...
```

When I load .../foods/new, I get this error:

```
undefined local variable or method `f' for #<#<Class:0x00007fdb4c036428>:0x00007fdb342a3890
```

Any tips would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Rails docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html). Please use `<%= render partial: "form", :locals => { :f => f  } %>` or `<%= render "form", :f => f %>` syntax.